# iOS Selenium test on a Linux Host

Tags: ios, linux, selenium, virtual-machine, selenium-grid

I'm want to config Selenium test on iOS VM Device on my Linux host ( Ubuntu ).
I know that I must use a MAC OS X VM which run my iOS Simulator but there is one thing I don't understand. How does the Linux host communicate with the iOS VM Device? 
Is there a way to make an iOS node of a Selenium Grid? Which technology should I use, and how implement it?

To sum up, my goal is to make a Linux host launch iOS Selenium test on a Mac OS X VM running iOS Simulator.

Thanks for helping!